# How to Convert XML Data into CSV format in XSLT

Tags: xml, templates, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

My xml input like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<EmployeeRequest xmlns="http://www.example.org"
   <EmployeeDetails>
     <FirstName>Khan</FirstName>
     <LastName>Joshi</LastName>
     <Age>30</Age>
   </EmployeeDetails>
   <EmployeeDetails>
     <FirstName>Josh</FirstName>
     <LastName>Luis</LastName>
     <Age>29</Age>
   </EmployeeDetails>
</EmployeeRequest>
```

But My Output should come like below.

```
FirstName, LastName, Age
Khan, joshi,30
Josh,Luis,29
```

Here EmployeeDetails is Unbound.Using template how to resolve this?

Please let me know how to get this output

Comment: **1.** Please select either XSLT 1.0 **or** XSLT 2.0 - not both. -- **2.** Please post your expected output **as code**. -- **3.** What have you tried? Show us your attempted XSLT, so that we won't have to start from scratch.

Comment: Using template how to resolve the above requirement in XSLT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The path `//*[not(*)]` gives you all the leaf elements (as you do not seem to be interested in the root `EmployeeRequest` and the container `EmployeeDetails`), then `<xsl:value-of select="//*[not(*)]/name()" separator=", "/>` would output the names. That assumes an XSLT 2.0 processor.

If you want to keep it generic you can use

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

<xsl:output method="text"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:value-of select="/*/*[1]/*/local-name()" separator=", "/>
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="/*/*"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*/*">
    <xsl:if test="position() > 1">
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:value-of select="*" separator=", "/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

see http://xsltransform.net/gWmuiK1 for an example.

Comment: Using Template give me one example. Because my EmployeeDetails element unbounded

Comment: I have added a sample using a template.

Comment: Thanks a lot Martin, as u said its work in xslt 2.0 but i tried in 1.0 some function not working .

Answer (score 0):

This is a pure XSLT 1.0 solution:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:e="http://www.example.org">

<xsl:output method="text"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//e:EmployeeDetails[1]" mode="heading"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//e:EmployeeDetails"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="e:EmployeeDetails" mode="heading">
    <xsl:for-each select="*">
        <xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/>
        <xsl:call-template name="comma"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="e:EmployeeDetails">
    <xsl:for-each select="*">
        <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
        <xsl:call-template name="comma"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="comma">
    <xsl:if test="position() != last()">,</xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```